# How to "stop" closing modal if form invalid

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form in a Semantic UI Modal, and I use the jQuery Form Plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#validation) to submit the form via ajax. The "submit" process of the form is triggered by the modal "ok" button. But if the form is invalid, the modal is still closed.

How can I "stop" the modal close procecedure?

Thanks a lot!

**edit**

Code snippets:

the modal:

```
    <div class="ui modal" id="add-item-modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Eintrag hinzufügen
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        {{ include('adachauerJobsBundle:CV/forms:training.html.twig') }}
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui buttons">
            <div class="ui button" onclick="$('#modal-form').reset();">Abbrechen</div>
            <div class="ui button primary" onclick="$('#modal-form').submit();">Speichern</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal show:

```
    $('.show-modal').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $($(this).attr('data-modal-id')).modal('show');
    });
```

Form submit:

```
    var cvDataTarget = '#cv-data-target';
$('.ajax-form').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
            for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) {
                if (!formData[i].value) {
                    console.log(0);
                    alert('Bitte fülle alle erforderlichen Felder aus, um den Eintrag zu speichern.');
                    $('#'+formData[i].name).focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        success: function(t) {
            console.log(t);
            if (t.success == true) {
                $(cvDataTarget).html($(cvDataTarget).html()+ t.html);
            } else {
                alert(t.error);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: Create the dialog with the button and onclick event instead of using inline: `modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {`

Comment: Ok, thats done. But how must be the "submit" function return? The modal still closes... "return false" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a `return false;` in the modal's callback to prevent it from closing:

```
$('.show-modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('data-modal-id')).modal('show',{
        onApprove : function() {
            return false; //block the modal here
        }
    });
});
```

And once you're done, you can call

```
$(theModal).modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Call preventDefault() just before submitting the form:

```
 $('#theSubmitButton').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#modal-form').submit();
 });
```

Modify the submit button by removing onclick() and giving "him" a name:

```
 <div class="ui button primary" id="theSubmitButton">Speichern</div>
```